# body being pushed down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working on this site, http://hidden.xx The problem is that the `<body>` is pushed down about 20px from the top. And that is causing problems at the bottom of the page where you can see that the background gradient is beeing repeated the last 20px. If you try to take out firebug or any other panel the area where the repetition is happening gets bigger.

I have tryed solving this but firebug gives me no clues of what is causing this behavior.
I try'd absolute positioning the body to the top and that sort of solves it, but the repeating area appears again if you pring out a panel from the bottom of the browser, like firebug etc.

edit: There was two issues, first issue was a margin collapse issue and was solved thanks to @zzzzBov. And the second issue was solved by adding `background-repeat:repeat-x;` to the body, thanks to @Alex

Comment: It's hard to trouble-shoot if you're working on the live site. (are you?) A dedicated test page helps alleviate that concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Margin collapsing strikes again](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)!

<sub>the margin on `#wrapper` is collapsing with `body`. You could change it to `padding: 20px 0` and `margin: 0 auto;`</sub>

Comment: Ty, this helped me. But the problem is still that when I bring out firebug panel from the bottom, the repeating color appears.

Comment: you're going to have issues with the repeating color if a scroll bar appears for any reason.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

`body{
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#377AA8, #589CCB) repeat-x scroll 0 0 #579BCA;
}`

Repeat the background only to the "X" (horizontal) and put the background color to the lightest color of the gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your stylesheet, I'd suggest trying to clear both the `padding` and `margin` on your `body` tag(set them to 0). If that fails, then I'd suggest clearing both on your navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Background-color in line 3 to `#589CCB`:

```
html {   background-color: #589CCB;}

/* line 20, ../sass/screen.scss */
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #589CCB; /*OLD: background: #377aa8;*/
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #377aa8), color-stop(100%, #589ccb));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#377aa8, #589ccb);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#377aa8, #589ccb);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#377aa8, #589ccb);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#377aa8, #589ccb);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#377aa8, #589ccb);
    }
```

Comment: This is not helping, because the repeating color is of the gradiant and not of the background property.